# Whats wrong with my AVL Tree deletion method?

Tags: java, data-structures, avl-tree

```
if(t == null) //If search is complete and no element is found
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x < t.data)
            t.left = delete(t.left, x);
        else if(x > t.data)
            t.right = delete(t.right, x);
        else if(t.left != null && t.right != null)
        {
            TreeNode temp = findMax(t.left);
            t.data = temp.data;
            t.left = delete(t.left, temp.data);
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode child = null;
            if(t.left == null)
                child = t.right;
            if(t.right == null)
                child = t.left;
            return child;
        }

        t.height = Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right)) + 1; //Update the height of TreeNodes
        t = balanceTree(t);

        return t;
    }
private TreeNode balanceTree(TreeNode t)
{
    if(getBalance(t) > 1) 
    {
        if (getBalance(t.left) >= 0)
            return singleRotateLeftToRight(t);
        else
            return doubleRotateLeftToRight(t);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (getBalance(t) < -1)
        {
            if (getBalance(t.right) <= 0)
                return singleRotateRightToLeft(t);
            else
                return doubleRotateRightToLeft(t);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AVLTree v = new AVLTree();
    v.insert(50);
    v.insert(40);
    v.insert(35);
    v.insert(37);
    v.insert(34);
    v.insert(55);
    v.insert(60);
    v.insert(54);
    v.insert(53);
    v.insert(52);
    v.insert(5);
    v.insert(4);
    v.insert(3);
    v.delete(40);
    v.delete(35);
    v.delete(37);
    v.delete(53);
    v.delete(60);
    v.insert(2);
    v.insert(6);
    v.delete(34);
    v.delete(6);
    v.delete(50);
    v.delete(4);
    v.delete(3);
    v.delete(2);






}
private TreeNode singleRotateLeftToRight(TreeNode k1) // (Utility Method) Performs single rotation of a TreeNode from left to right
{ 
    TreeNode k2 = k1.left;
    k1.left = k2.right;
    k2.right = k1;
    k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.left), height(k1.right)) + 1;
    k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.left), height(k2.right)) + 1;
    return k2;
}

private TreeNode singleRotateRightToLeft(TreeNode k1) //(Utility Method) Performs single rotation of a TreeNode from right to left
{ 
    TreeNode k2 = k1.right;
    k1.right = k2.left;
    k2.left = k1;
    k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.left), height(k1.right)) + 1;
    k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.left), height(k2.right)) + 1;
    return k2;
}

private TreeNode doubleRotateLeftToRight(TreeNode k1) //(Utility Method) Performs double rotation of a TreeNode from left to right
{ 
    k1.left = singleRotateRightToLeft(k1.left);
    return singleRotateLeftToRight(k1);
}

private TreeNode doubleRotateRightToLeft(TreeNode k1) //(Utility Method) Performs double rotation of a TreeNode from right to left
{ 
    k1.right = singleRotateLeftToRight(k1.right);
    return singleRotateRightToLeft(k1);
}

private int getBalance(TreeNode t) { //Returns the difference between the height of the left TreeNode and right TreeNode (utility method)
    if(t == null)
        return -1;
    return height(t.left) - height(t.right);
}
```

the insertion code works fine but when it comes to deletion I get problems its like some tree nodes disappear and I'm sure that the rotation codes are fine but whats wrong with my code when I delete the tree node with 2 the nodes with 54 and 55 are missing and I'm pretty sure there are no problems with the deletion but it should be with the rotations or maybe I'm balancing the wrong nodes I don't know.

Comment: You forgot to put a language tag. Please [edit] to add that.

Comment: What if `t.left` has no elements, and `findMax(t.left)` returns `null`? You should do a `findMin(t.right)` just in case that happens.

Comment: That means the node has one child and it goes for the other deletion condition but I figured out what was the problem it seems i needed to do this root = delete(root, element); in the public method not the utility that solved it